# Is there any significance if I add an international conference abstract details where I am a second author in my CV?

Tags: conference, authorship, abstract

I have two international conference abstract where my name is as a second author, There is any significance in that if I add it in my CV?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you not add it? Second author is still author, not non-author. Add it. It will speak for itself.

If these are your most important accomplishments then you have a way to go, but, even for a distinguished academic, the CV should be complete.

The significance may be small, but not *nothing*.